# Pagination in Ext Tree

Tags: extjs

I am using ext js javascript library.

This is regarding pagination for ext tree.

While loading tree, i am fetching complete tree data, whereas I wish to fetch only the top level or root level or maybe max upto 2 levels.

I wish to fetch data at more depths, on demand. If user expands the node, then i wish to fetch the data for that node.

My focus is on implementing pagination for the tree.

Can i use Ext.direct for more efficient performance? My backend is delphi/pascal.

What is the more efficient way for using something similar to pagination in grid in ext tree?

Thanks.

Comment: Is [delphi] tag relevant here?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no paging support in the TreeStore at this moment.

In regard of loading tree data, the TreeStore by default won't try to load the whole tree, it will make the following call instead:

```
GET http://your_web_service/some_tree?node=root
```

When user clicks on a tree node to expand it, say the node's id is "12", the TreeStore will try to fetch data by:

```
GET http://your_web_service/some_tree?node=12
```

So, how to deal with the `node` parameter and decide what to return to the client are the responsibilities of your web service.