# Is it possible to send start and limit parameters in ajax request using Extjs 5 TreeStore?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I've created an Ext.tree.Panel view.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.requests.view.QueryRequestsGridView', {
    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
    useArrows: true,
    rootVisible: false,
    singleExpand: true,
    bind: {
        store: '{queryRequestsGrid}'
    },
    viewConfig:{
        markDirty: false
    },
    columns: [
        { text: 'Id', dataIndex: 'id', flex: 3},
        { xtype: 'treecolumn', text: 'Name', dataIndex: 'name', flex: 6},
        { text: 'ControlType', dataIndex: 'controlType', flex: 4, sortable: false},
        { text: 'Description', dataIndex: 'description', flex: 6}
    ],
    dockedItems: [{
            xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
            bind: {
                store: '{queryRequestsGrid}'
            },
            displayInfo: true
        }]
    }]
});
```

As I can see from the docs the store of Ext.tree.Panel should be Ext.data.TreeStore.

```
Ext.define('MyApp.requests.model.QueryRequestsGridModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeModel',
    fields: [
        {name: 'id'},
        {name: 'name'},
        {name: 'controlType'},
        {name: 'description'}
    ]
});

Ext.define('MyApp.requests.store.QueryRequestsGridStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    model: 'MyApp.requests.model.QueryRequestsGridModel',
    pageSize: 10,
    alias: 'store.queryRequestsGrid',
    root: {
        expanded: false
    },
    remoteSort: true,
    proxy: {
        startParam: 'start',
        limitParam: 'limit',
        pageParam: undefined,
        sortParam: undefined,
        noCache: false,
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'ucis.json'
    }
});
```

Now on view creation the TreeStore data is requested using the following url without start and limit params but with nodeParam instead:

```
ucis.json?node=root
```

If to replace Ext.data.TreeStore with Ext.data.Store the following url will be sent:

```
ucis.json?offset=0&limit=10
```

The question is: does a treestore support start and limit pagingtoolbar parameters?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily paginate a list. But the concept of tree pagination isn't disambiguous, I fear.

When thinking of the tree like an indented list, there would evidently be pages with leaves which are neither root nor have parents that have been sent to the client (because they are not on the page you requested). But the TreeStore does not work like an indented list; it works with a root and child nodes. This is why there is no builtin pagination support for TreeStore. Furthermore, PagingToolbar can only work with a list of nodes, not with a tree.

As per [Pagination in Ext Tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17130982/pagination-in-ext-tree), TreeStore does not require a full tree; it can work with a tree that is not fully loaded, and can dynamically fetch child nodes of a certain node whenever you expand the node. This is what you are using.

When thinking of every node's child nodes as a list, there is no builtin way to split the 1000 child nodes of a node into pages automatically. You can, however, extend the TreeStore to allow for that; there is no hard technical boundary against it. But you would have to extend the TreeGrid with a BufferedRenderer as well, which is not as easy as it may sound. The biggest hurdle would be using `pagingToolbar`, you won't be easily able to use that or extend from it, since it binds to the grid and works with that, but you need pagination on every node's child list. Because, if your root has a list of 1000 nodes and you open one of these nodes with 500 child nodes, how would the pagingToolbar know which node's children you want to page through?

Comment: Thx for your answer! What if to count only the 1st level nodes (under the root) in case of pagination? For example, the first level nodes are populated from the url_1. The url_1 also contains information of total number of such 1st level nodes. On every 1st level node expand event 2nd level nodes are populated from url_2 using uniq id of 1st level nodes (url_2/node1). For pagination itself the number of 1st level nodes is only important. The only problem is, how to differ 1st and 2nd level nodes if they already have been populated into the same store?

Comment: @fen1ksss No, the problem is how to tell the store to use different URLs for both calls. [Differing between 1st level and 2nd level should be easy](http://dev.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.0/examples/kitchensink/#heterogeneous-tree).

Comment: That's actually is not a big problem. You can specify different urls inside beforeload listener of a TreeStore using operation parameter. if (operation.node.getId() === 'root') {1st level nodes proxy url } else {2nd level}. Thank you for the kitchen link, I'll try to sum up both things.

Answer (score 0):

Answering to my own question:

Yes, it is possible to send start and limit parameters from viewcontroller (for example, on afterrender event) using store.load

```
store.load({
    params: {
        start: 0,
        limit: store.pageSize
    }
});
```

The TreeStore will not send those parameters itself on the first load because does not support pagination from the box.